# Using RowMapper for LocalDate

Tags: java, rowmapper

I have a class `RowMapperFactory`  that can return an `Employee` in particular:

```
new Employee(
                            new BigInteger("7499"),
                            new FullName("JOHN", "ALLEN", "MARIA"),
                            Position.SALESMAN,
                            LocalDate.of(1981, 2, 20),
                            new BigDecimal("1600")
                    )
```

but I want create a generale form. For  `new BigInteger`, `new FullName`, `Position`, `new BigDecimal` I did it, but how do it for `LocalDate`. `LocalDate` must take date from  column `hired`. I try
`LocalDate.from((TemporalAccessor) resultSet.getDate("hired"))`, but write that `hired column not found`. How to solve it?

```
public class RowMapperFactory {

    public RowMapper<Employee> employeeRowMapper() {
        return new RowMapper<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
                return new Employee(
                        new BigInteger(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id"))),
                        new FullName(resultSet.getString("firstname"),resultSet.getString("lastName"),resultSet.getString("middleName") ),
                        Position.valueOf(resultSet.getString("position")),
                        LocalDate.from((TemporalAccessor) resultSet.getDate("hired")),
                        new BigDecimal(resultSet.getInt("salary"))
                );
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: by checking if that column exists, and whether or not you are using the right datatype

Comment: but column exists? How to do it

Comment: 'but column exists', not according to that error message. That problem is not related to the mapping, it specifically tells you: "hired column not found"

Comment: What data type does this column hold? Are you sure it is a `TemporalAccessor`? The error message definitely tells you the column could not be found, you may have a typo somewhere else...

Comment: this column hold LocalDate data types format "1980-12-17". it is not a TemporalAccessor

Comment: but how else to access the data?

Comment: if it's not a TemporalAccessor, why are you trying to parse it to one?

Comment: So it most likely holds formatted `String`s and no `java.sql.Date`s (which is what you get when you call `getDate(...)` on a `ResultSet`) and that would also explain why the column cannot be found: There is no column named `'hired'` that holds DATE or DATETIME values. Try `LocalDate.parse(resultSet.getString("hired")` or if it really returns a `Date`, then convert it via `Instant`, but then you really need the `getDate(..)` call.

Answer (score 0):

If the columnName `"hired"`, is not working, try with index and see if you can find this column you are looking for.

After it is found, you could retrieve it in LocalDate format as such:

```
 LocalDate date = resultSet.getObject(colIndex, LocalDate.class);
```